# Linq expression with nullable

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

Looks like stupid question, but I just dont get it.
My entity:

```
public class Page
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    //...
    public int? ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

In controller:

```
db.Pages.First(x => x.ParentId == null);
```

Works as expected (returns some element).
But:

```
int? test = null;
db.Pages.First(x => x.ParentId == test);
```

Throws `Sequence contains no elements`

What do I miss?

Comment: Are you using linq-to-entities? This has nothing specific to do with asp.net-mvc?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I believe there's an oddity around nulls with some LINQ providers. Try:

```
var query = db.Pages.First(x => (test != null && x.ParentId == test) ||
                                (test == null && x.ParentId == null));
```

Alternatively, use different queries for the different situations:

```
var query = test == null ? db.Pages.First(x => x.ParentId == null)
                         : db.Pages.First(x => x.ParentId == test);
```

Basically this is because SQL treats NULL as unequal to itself, so:

```
WHERE X = Y
```

will still fail if both X and Y are null values. Using the `== null` part (with a *literal* null) forces a conversion to `ISNULL` or whatever the SQL equivalent is.

I agree it's a pain, and someone else may have a better workaround, but this may help you get going.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this as a workaround:

```
int? test = null;
if(test.HasValue) {
 db.Pages.First(x => x.ParentId == test.Value);
} else {
 db.Pages.First(x => x.ParentId == null);
}
```

I'm assuming since `int?` is actually a `Nullable<int>` our linq-to-entities provider isn't comparing things right.

Answer (score 1):

Try this (*modified according to gdoron's comment. It now is exactly what gideon posted, so please accept his instead of mine*):

```
int? test = null;
if(test.HasValue) {
    db.Pages.First(x => x.ParentId == test.Value);
} else {
    db.Pages.First(x => x.ParentId == null);
}
```

Comment: Won't work. `Value - The value of the current Nullable(Of T) object if the HasValue property is true. ==> An exception is thrown if the HasValue property is false. <==`

Comment: thx for this solution, but i just wanted to understand that oddity of LINQ